# How to add custom claim to a token in Duende under Client Credential flow?

Tags: jwt, duende-identity-server, clientcredential, identityserver5

Currently, I'm using a working Client Credential Flow. I'd like to extend the behavior of the IDP and add a claim besides the ones distributed automatically based on the client.

Checking the [docs for Client Credential Flow](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/1_client_credentials/), didn't give me much. What I hoped for, was to implement [`IProfileService`](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/services/profile_service/) but noticed that it's not being invoked (since it's handling **user** claims, not client claims). Checking the [docs for the other services](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/services/), I couldn't recognize anything similar to what I need (possibly missing the obvious due to confusion).

Let's assume the scenario that a service accesses the client, passing the correct client ID and secret but also a GUID in the header or in the payload together with the grant type etc. Now, I'd like to issue a JWT with the claims based on the client but with two alternations. Partly, I'd like to add a custom claim (based on the passed GUID). Partly, I'd like to remove one of the provided claims (also based on the passed GUID).

How can I do that?

The efforts gave me mostly hits on [Auth0's stuff](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/customize-tokens-using-hooks-with-client-credentials-flow) and some for Curity and others. Duende must have something similar as well, don't they?

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71396042/1525840) to that telling me "no" but I feel it's not precise. I don't want to change to the obsolete Resource Owner Flow (deprecation and requirement for user interaction). I feel that it should be possible to pick a custom passed value and somehow horse around with the issued JWT. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516993/is-it-possible-to-add-customization-claim-in-client-credential-flow) suggests that it's (theoretically) possible but they did that in Azure and I host my own authority.

The best shot I've seen is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75094301/1525840) regarding [`ITokenResponseGenerator`](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/response_handling/token_response_generator/). However, both mention something about DI and a factory, which puzzles me, as there's no samples to check out. So I can't try it out, regrettably...

Is that the proper approach and if so, how can I push in my custom implementation of the generator to be applied?

Answer (score 0):

We need to extend TokenResponseGenerator class in Duende and override ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync as below.

```
internal class CustomTokenResponseGenerator : TokenResponseGenerator
{
    public CustomTokenResponseGenerator(ISystemClock clock, ITokenService tokenService, IRefreshTokenService refreshTokenService, IScopeParser scopeParser, IResourceStore resources, IClientStore clients, ILogger<TokenResponseGenerator> logger) : base(clock, tokenService, refreshTokenService, scopeParser, resources, clients, logger)
    {
    }
    protected override async Task<TokenResponse> ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync(TokenRequestValidationResult request)
    {
        var result = await base.ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync(request);

        if (result != null)
        {
            //If you need to get user details you can use below context
            
             var user = request.ValidatedRequest.Subject; 
             var userClaims = user.Claims;  
           
             if (result.Custom == null)
             {
                result.Custom = new Dictionary<string, object>();
             }
             result.Custom.Add("CustomProperty","SomeValue");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Once we have defined the above implementation we can register to DI

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITokenResponseGenerator, CustomTokenResponseGenerator>();
```

This will override the default implementation of Duende.

Comment: Are you certain it's not `ProcessClientCredentialsRequestAsync(...)` that I should override (since I'm trying to add custom tokens in **client credential** flow and not in **auth code** flow? (Apologies for the late reply. Work overload and sickness.)